# Better muscle memory(dancing) after weight lifting

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, workout, dancing

I tend to learn dance moves much more quickly after I've had a weight lifting workout or even during. Of course, not from the very exhausting ones, but still with huge muscles pump.

Why is that? One of my assumptions is because I'm flexing more while doing the moves. It is still confusing, though. If that was the case, wouldn't every dancer do a weight lifting workout before a dance workout? And most don't.

Comment: Are you normally warming up before dancing?

Answer (score 1):

i also go to the gym before my dance lessons, im not sure what kind of dance you do but mine is zouk. doing a workout before hand as long as the weights are not to heavy is great as it warms up ur body ready to dance. doing stretches before dance classes also helps.